# How to print only constraint message from BeanValidationException

Tags: apache-camel, bean-validation

I want to print only constraint message but apachecamel printing complete message like

Bean Code part

```
@NotNull(message="Validation Error name value Missing.")
private String name;
```

Router Code

```
    onException(BeanValidationException.class) 
    .handled(true) 
    .process( new FailedResponseProcessor() );
```

Processor code

```
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    Exception e = exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, Exception.class); 
    Response response = new Response();
    response.setRequestStatus("Failed");
    response.setRequestMessage(e.getMessage());
```

Following is response received

```
<response>
  <requestStatus>Failed</requestStatus>
  <requestMessage>Validation failed for: org.my.Request@1b8a0be3 errors: [property: name; value: null; constraint: Validation Error name value Missing.; ]. Exchange[ID-WCB00073679-49595-1507251546181-0-1]</requestMessage>
</response>
```

Comment: Isn't there some kind of BeanValidationException being thrown that has APIs to get constraint message and other details. In the processor code you just work with the generic Exception class, try to find out its really type and see what API it has

Answer (score 0):

Below works for me

```
BeanValidationException bve = (BeanValidationException) exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT);
Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>> constraintViolations   =   bve.getConstraintViolations();
ConstraintViolation<Object> constraintViolation = constraintViolations.iterator().next();
System.out.println( constraintViolation.getMessage() );
```